# Output the first image url of a specific div for og:image tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I hope the title is self-explanatory.

Basically I have the following code, and I wish to get the URL of the first image inside of my .content div so I can place it my header's og:image tag.

```
<div class="content">
<img src="image1.jpg">
<img src="image2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Even if you get this working in javascript, crawlers and bots won't be able to pull the `og:image` because javascript runs on the client side after the page is rendered. You need to parse your page server-side and add the `og:image` at that time.

Comment: Good to know. Can't get it to work anyway. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 1):

For get the `src` of first `img` element from div and put that value in meta tag content, do something like this.

```
//getting div 
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];

//getting first img element  and it's src from div
var firstImgSrc = div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;

//creating meta tag, assigned image source to content and appending into head tag
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.content = firstImgSrc;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

Comment: That looks great, but I'm still confused on how to output the image url to this code.

    <meta property="og:image" content="image url"/>

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.content > img:first-child').attr('src')` or `$('div.content > img)[0].src`

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstImgUrl = $('.content img:first-of-type').attr('src');
```